# Insert or replace multiple matches of the same string with a running counter

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a RIS (text) file that looks roughly likes this:

```
mylist <- c("TI  - a", "AU  - b", "ER  -", " ",
          "TI  - c", "AU  - d", "ER  -", " ",
          "TI  - e", "AU  - f", "ER  -")
```

I would like to insert a running ID tag as follows

```
mylist_with_ids <- c("TI  - a", "AU  - b", "ID  - 1", "ER  -", " ",
                   "TI  - c", "AU  - d", "ID  - 2", "ER  -", " ",
                   "TI  - e", "AU  - f", "ID  - 3", "ER  -")
```

My original approach was to write a `stringr::str_replace` loop, where I generate the ID list beforehand.

```
cc_id_replace <- paste0("ID  - ", 1:3, "\nER  -")
for (i in 1:3) {
  mylist_with_ids <- str_replace(mylist, "^ER  -", cc_id_replace[i])
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work for more than one reason. What might be a better way?
(There exist many regex and multiple array questions, but I couldn't figure out an answer so far.)

Comment: Since you're always looking for a strict string match, why are you using regex? https://xkcd.com/1171/ ... unless you're hoping for https://xkcd.com/208/.

Comment: Should the `ID` element be insterted before the `ER -`?

Comment: @nicola yes - ER stands for end record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
list[list == "ER  -"] <- paste("ID   -", seq_along(which(list == "ER  -")), "\nER  -")
```

Comment: This turns the third value into `"ID   - 1 \nER  -"` instead of `"ID   - 1", "ER  -"`. Though from here you could `unlist(strsplit(list, "\n"))` to get the same result.

Comment: @r2evans I know. I was going to add that, but it sounded like the result was going to be written to a text file, so I thought that was superfluous.

Comment: BTW: `1:length(...)` is great when it works, but when `which` returns nothing, this will still create a vector. Try `1:length(integer(0))` and see that it produces `[1] 1 0`, a vector of length 2 (it's doing `1:0`), instead of a vector of length 0. It is must safer (and defensive) to replace `1:length(...)` with `seq_len(length(...))` or just `seq_along(integer(0))`, as in my example they both correctly return `integer(0)`.

Comment: @r2evans thanks, fair point. I usually use `seq_along` myself for the reasons you describe, but thought for this particular case it was pretty clear that the length wouldn't be zero.

Comment: I don't disagree that it appears that way ... but if this is ever productionized (used in an automated fashion where it is feasible that it is just `mylist <- c("TI  - a", "AU  - b")`, then I argue it's much better to be defensive up-front. Also, with "budding programmers", I find it best to recommend solutions that are more robust ... or at least note the assumption in the answer. I personally would be interested in some "agent" in R that looks for the use of `1:length(...)` and produces a message or warning, to warn of potential problems ... perhaps that's the "Hal9000" of R parsers :-)

Comment: In fact ... https://github.com/jimhester/lintr/issues/43#issuecomment-552857792!

Comment: I used a version of this suggestion in the end, but I'm not sure if it is the "best" answer for SO purposes. Please advise what I should mark as answer.

Comment: @Rico it's really up to you to choose the answer you think best. I will incorporate the changes made by r2evans to make sure everyone is happy, but whether you mark this answer, or another, or none, is entirely up to you!

Answer (score 0):

I think run-length encoding can be used here.

(BTW: I don't like using `list` as a variable name, since it is such a frequently used R function. While R knows well which you mean when referenced, it is feasible that this can be fooled, and troubleshooting that will be problematic. So I've named it `mylist` here.)

```r
mylist <- c("TI  - a", "AU  - b", "ER  -", " ",
            "TI  - c", "AU  - d", "ER  -", " ",
            "TI  - e", "AU  - f", "ER  -")
non_ER_runs <- rle(mylist == "ER  -")
non_ER_runs
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:6] 2 1 3 1 3 1
#   values : logi [1:6] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

RLE tells us how many are in each category. For us, the category is "matches and does not match". The `$values` vector here tells us that the first elements *do not* match (`FALSE`), and there are two of them. The second batch *does* match (`TRUE`) and is one long. Etc.

```r
inds <- cumsum(non_ER_runs$lengths)
newlist <- mapply(function(a,b) mylist[a:b], c(1, 1+head(inds, n=-1)), inds)
newlist
# [[1]]
# [1] "TI  - a" "AU  - b"
# [[2]]
# [1] "ER  -"
# [[3]]
# [1] " "       "TI  - c" "AU  - d"
# [[4]]
# [1] "ER  -"
# [[5]]
# [1] " "       "TI  - e" "AU  - f"
# [[6]]
# [1] "ER  -"
```

Okay, so we've broken each batch into its own vector. Using the return from `rle` again, we can choose just the elements where we want to append something:

```r
newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ]
# [[1]]
# [1] "ER  -"
# [[2]]
# [1] "ER  -"
# [[3]]
# [1] "ER  -"
Map(function(vec, vec2) c(vec, vec2),
      newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ],
      sprintf("ID  - %i", seq_along(newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ])))
# [[1]]
# [1] "ER  -"   "ID  - 1"
# [[2]]
# [1] "ER  -"   "ID  - 2"
# [[3]]
# [1] "ER  -"   "ID  - 3"
```

Now it's just a matter of replacing the list elements with the new elements, then `unlist`ing it.

```r
newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ] <-
  Map(function(vec, vec2) c(vec, vec2),
      newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ],
      sprintf("ID  - %i", seq_along(newlist[ non_ER_runs$values ])))
newlist <- unlist(newlist)
newlist
#  [1] "TI  - a" "AU  - b" "ER  -"   "ID  - 1" " "      
#  [6] "TI  - c" "AU  - d" "ER  -"   "ID  - 2" " "      
# [11] "TI  - e" "AU  - f" "ER  -"   "ID  - 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ris <- c("TI  - a", "AU  - b", "ER  -", " ",
          "TI  - c", "AU  - d", "ER  -", " ",
          "TI  - e", "AU  - f", "ER  -")
```

Another suggestion using dirty for loops ;)

1.Find position to insert ID element before (here using a bit of regex). Use `pos` vector to generate right number of IDs:

```
pos <- grep("^ER", ris)
ids <- paste0("ID = ", seq_along(pos))
```

2.Loop through all positions, insert, paste, repeat (and update `pos`):

```
for (i in seq_along(pos)) {
  ris <- c(ris[1:(pos[i]-1)], ids[i], ris[pos[i]:length(ris)] )
  pos <- pos + 1
}

ris
```

Returns:

```
[1] "TI  - a" "AU  - b" "ID = 1"  "ER  -"  
[5] " "       "TI  - c" "AU  - d" "ID = 2" 
[9] "ER  -"   " "       "TI  - e" "AU  - f"
[13] "ID = 3"  "ER  -"
```